# What is the science behind CFCs depleting the ozone layer?

Tags: atmosphere

Specifically, if the daily production of ozone and cfc were at most 400 million and 3k tons, respectively, would each mol of cfc be able to destroy tens of thousands of mols of ozone? All the sources I can find show cfc being much less potent than that.

Comment: please share the references you are discussing

Comment: I don't see what the daily production has to do with the question about the number of mols.

Comment: The question raised in the title, *What is the science behind CFCs depleting the ozone layer*, is readily answered by asking that question of **the** internet oracle (i.e., google). Even the lesser oracles (e.g., yahoo and bing) can answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

I guess nobody has given DJ Sims the simple answer he/she wants because such a generalized question is indeterminate. The chlorine is relatively stable, so 'how many ozone mols are destroyed' depends upon the availability of relatively short-lived ozone. In a dry atmosphere this is very much a function of temperature. At -50 deg C ozone's half life is about 3 months, but at 0 deg C it is only about 5 days. It also depends upon humidity, pH and a swag of associated high-atmospheric reactions. The ozone availability is also a function of ozone's regeneration rate.

Comment: @DJSims That's a creative interpretation. Gordon says that you cannot give a simple figure because it depends on too many factors. You conclude that *thus* there is no evidence. How about you doing some homework first and answering the comments under your question? That would help people to know what to answer *to* without having to write an entire textbook .